# SQL ORDER BY CASE + ORDER BY ID DESC

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to order my table by two paramenters one is ´status´ where I have a perfectly working CASE order and the second column is ´ID´ where I simply want to order the results of the cases by their table ID in order to have the newest result on top in the sorted case.

Thats my current query :

```
    SELECT ID, status 
FROM omv_tabelle 
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN status = 'ANMELDUNG' THEN '1'
WHEN status = 'KUNDE' THEN '2'
WHEN status = 'OMV_ANTRAG' THEN '3'
WHEN status = 'ABLEHNUNG' THEN '4' END ASC,
ID DESC
```

I have no clue how to add ID into that sorting while not destroying the case funktionality

my current output looks like this:

```
407 KEIN_INTERESSE
406 KEIN_INTERESSE
405 KEIN_INTERESSE
397 KEIN_INTERESSE
396 KEIN_INTERESSE
411 ANMELDUNG
1   ANMELDUNG
6   KUNDE
5   KUNDE
4   KUNDE
3   KUNDE
2   KUNDE
394 ABLEHNUNG
393 ABLEHNUNG
392 ABLEHNUNG
391 ABLEHNUNG
390 ABLEHNUNG
```

So the ordering of the statuses is wrong :/

It should be :

```
411 ANMELDUNG
1   ANMELDUNG
6   KUNDE
5   KUNDE
4   KUNDE
3   KUNDE
2   KUNDE
394 ABLEHNUNG
393 ABLEHNUNG
392 ABLEHNUNG
391 ABLEHNUNG
390 ABLEHNUNG
407 KEIN_INTERESSE
406 KEIN_INTERESSE
405 KEIN_INTERESSE
397 KEIN_INTERESSE
396 KEIN_INTERESSE
```

Comment: See the edited answer. If it still doesn't satisfies you then explain what is wrong with your ordering...

Comment: Every downvote should be explained. I provided a detailed issue with my current outcome..

Comment: No downvote from me. Just a remark: Query and output do not match. 'KEIN_INTERESSE' would come last, because it would get an implicit sort key of NULL. I suppose you still have `ELSE status`, which would get you 'KEIN_INTERESSE' first, because Oracle treats '1' > 'K'. (And a status '1 x ABGELEHNT' would come between '1' and '2' It is a bad idea to create a sort key for some statuses and use status itself as a sort key for the others :-) This is just to exlain what happens. How to do it properly is shown in Giorgi Nakeuri's answer.

Comment: @noa-dev, never mind. There are always people who just downvote without any reason. I remember I had a problem and asked question. And got 2 downvotes :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900996/ssrs-report-parameter But in general when you are getting downvoted you should reread your question. May be there is something you can improove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Order by `ID desc` after the `case statement`. I don't understand your `akhtungs`, but this relies on your sample output:

```
SELECT * 
FROM omv_tabelle 
ORDER BY CASE
              WHEN status = 'open' THEN 1
              WHEN status = 'pending' THEN 2
              WHEN status = 'closed' THEN 3 END,
         ID DESC
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT ID, status 
FROM omv_tabelle 
ORDER BY CASE
              WHEN status = 'ANMELDUNG' THEN 1
              WHEN status = 'KUNDE' THEN 2
              WHEN status = 'OMV_ANTRAG' THEN 3
              WHEN status = 'ABLEHNUNG' THEN 4 
              ELSE 5 END ASC,
         status,
         ID desc
```

Comment: It orders the "opens", "pendings" and "closed" perfectly by ID among them but unfortunately the whole package is sorted wrong now. In my example I have 5 total different status values and they are not being outputed as written in the when statements. Let me update my question quickly

Comment: Ok, provide sample output and explain what is wrong with ordering.